# l3 update bug, from earlier today?

Tags: expl3

EDIT: Problem identified, MWE here:

```
% !TeX program = LuaLaTeX
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\let\myaddfontfeatures\addfontfeatures
\let\addfontfeatures\relax
%% This works, with l3 2017/02/10 and fontspec-luatex 2017/02/12,
%% and prior versions:
\DeclareDocumentCommand \AddFontFeatures { m } {%%%%%%
  \myaddfontfeatures{#1}%
}
\let\addfontfeatures\AddFontFeatures
%% This fails, with l3 2017/02/10 and fontspec 2017/02/12:
%% However, it works with l3 2017/02/07 and fontspec-luatex 2017/01/24.
% \DeclareDocumentCommand \addfontfeatures { m } {%%%%%%
%   \myaddfontfeatures{#1}%
% }
%%
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
Whatever.\par
{\addfontfeatures{Letters=SmallCaps} Whatever.}\par
Whatever.\par
\end{document}
```

In my original question, I wondered if there was a bug in the 2017/02/10 updates to l3. Second guess would be fontspec, 2017/02/12. I had known-good code that ran prior to those updates, but failed by hanging in compilation (no error messages).

As you can see from the early comments below, I was directed to look for possible expansion problems. But it turned out that expansion had nothing to do with it. The problem was in the above code.

Originally (commented out, above) I re-defined a document command without going through an intermediary step. That code worked just fine, prior to the updates. If it was erronoeus code on my part, it nevertheless went through OK. But the updates caused it to hang, probably through a self-reference problem.

The fixed code uses an intermediary definition, and has no problem.

A quick glance through xparse and fontspec-luatex did not reveal why there was a change, but I'm not an expert in that stuff.

Comment: Which versions are you comparing? Do you by any change use `\NewDocumentCommand` (or `Renew` or `Declare`) with no arguments and a definition which includes anything non-L3-ish (e.g. `\expandafter` would be non-3ish)? This is not from today, though. (Do you update every day? Why?)

Comment: Packages from 2017/02/07 are good. Packages from this morning, which I believe are 2017/02/10 or later, not good. I do not have any \NewDocumentCommand. I have some `\DeclareDocumentCommand`. None of them have `\expandafter` but some have `\xdef` which is necessary there. The expanded item is simple text.

Comment: The problematic code (which I re-loaded) is indeed 2017/02/10. Changing to `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand` did not help, for the commands with `\xdef` inside. Likewise, if I rip out all the `\xdef` routines, and use `\DeclareDocumentCommand`, same bad behavior.

Comment: I had a similar issue. In my case, I had some simple macro I used as an argument into \widthof. After some hair pulling, it turned out the issue was resolved if I use \DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand instead of \NewDocumentCommand. But in my case, the body of the macro was indeed very simple and completely expandable. I guess somehow NewDocumentCommand does something destroying expandability (calc was complaining about \tex_let: or so I remember.). Might be related.

Comment: We will need an example here: there's not a 'known issue' that this sounds like.

Comment: @balcinus We have altered some code but as things created by `\NewDocumentCommand` are not intended to expand the old behaviour is arguably faulty anyway.

Comment: Add  \show\x in your class/preamble in various places and compile on a command line. Then you can narrow down the place where it starts to misbehave.

Comment: " None of them have \expandafter but some have `\xdef` which is necessary there. The expanded item is simple text." You should narrow down to an example using that. using `\xdef`  would be wrong always, you may have got lucky previously and an infinite loop now, that's not impossible but hard to confirm without an example.

Comment: Will investigate today. Might be "your tomorrow" before I can narrow this down. At least now I have some places I can look in the code.

Comment: @JosephWright Problem identified, MWE provided. Apparently the l3 update exposed something in my code that was previously passed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Got MWE, See my remark to JW.

Comment: Your code shows you were using unsupported syntax.

Comment: @egreg Apparently yes, unsupported syntax! The good news is that I discovered it now. This is not the first time I have done it. If there had been an error message (instead of hanging without error) I probably would have discovered it myself, before posting here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is essentially the same situation that led to the creation of the `letltxmacro` package.

With

```
\let\myaddfontfeatures\addfontfeatures
```

you define `\myaddfontfeatures` to be the same as the “user level” macro `\addfontfeatures`. Until the last update to `xparse`, macros only taking mandatory arguments used a streamlined definition, so if you did

```
\show\addfontfeatures
```

you would have received information such as

```
\addfontfeatures=\protected macro:
#1->\fontspec_if_fontspec_font:TF [...]
```

Starting from the last update, the streamlining is no longer used and you get

```
> \addfontfeatures=\protected macro:
->\__xparse_start:nNNnnn {m}\addfontfeatures  \addfontfeatures code {\__xparse_grab_m_1:w }{}{}.
```

which tells us the “real code” is kept in `\addfontfeatures code` (yes, with a space in the macro name).

Now `\myaddfontfeatures` is set to this meaning. If you do

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand\addfontfeatures{m}{...}
```

you will create an infinite loop as soon as you use `\addfontfeatures`. Indeed, this will execute `\addfontfeatures code` that contains a call to `\myaddfontfeatures`, which in turn will call `\addfontfeatures code`…

Infinite loop.

The current definition of `\addfontfeatures` can be found in `fontspec-luatex.sty` (or `-xetex`, it's the same):

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand \addfontfeatures {m}
 {
  \fontspec_if_fontspec_font:TF
   {
    \group_begin:
      \keys_set_known:nnN {fontspec-addfeatures} {#1} \l__fontspec_tmp_tl
      \prop_get:cnN {g__fontspec_ \f@family _prop} {options} \l__fontspec_options_tl
      \prop_get:cnN {g__fontspec_ \f@family _prop} {fontname} \l__fontspec_fontname_tl
      \bool_set_true:N \l__fontspec_disable_defaults_bool
      \use:x
       {
        \__fontspec_select_font_family:nn
          { \l__fontspec_options_tl , #1 } {\l__fontspec_fontname_tl}
       }
    \group_end:
    \fontfamily\l_fontspec_family_tl\selectfont
   }
   {
    \__fontspec_warning:nx {addfontfeatures-ignored} {#1}
   }
  \ignorespaces
 }
\cs_set_eq:NN \addfontfeature \addfontfeatures
```

It would be better if this followed the guidelines:

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand \addfontfeatures {m}
 {
  \fontspec_addfontfeatures:n { #1 }
 }
\cs_set_eq:NN \addfontfeature \addfontfeatures
\cs_new_protected:Nn \fontspec_addfontfeatures:n
 {
  \fontspec_if_fontspec_font:TF
   {
    \group_begin:
      \keys_set_known:nnN {fontspec-addfeatures} {#1} \l__fontspec_tmp_tl
      \prop_get:cnN {g__fontspec_ \f@family _prop} {options} \l__fontspec_options_tl
      \prop_get:cnN {g__fontspec_ \f@family _prop} {fontname} \l__fontspec_fontname_tl
      \bool_set_true:N \l__fontspec_disable_defaults_bool
      \use:x
       {
        \__fontspec_select_font_family:nn
          { \l__fontspec_options_tl , #1 } {\l__fontspec_fontname_tl}
       }
    \group_end:
    \fontfamily\l_fontspec_family_tl\selectfont
   }
   {
    \__fontspec_warning:nx {addfontfeatures-ignored} {#1}
   }
  \ignorespaces
 }
```

so you could do

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand{\addfontfeatures}{m}
 {
  <code before>
  \fontspec_addfontfeatures:n { #1 }
  <code after>
 }
\cs_set_eq:NN \addfontfeature \addfontfeatures
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

without needing multiple `\let` steps.

Alas, it doesn't follow the guidelines. `;-(`

---

If what you want is to disable `\addfontfeatures{Color=<color>}`, the best strategy is to disable the `Color` key:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { fontspec }
 {
  Color .code:n = ,
  Colour .code:n = ,
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Abc {\addfontfeatures{Color=red} Abc}

\end{document}
```

You could add a warning:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\msg_new:nnn { RobtA } { invalid-key }
 {
  Specifying~'Color=#1'~is~disabled
 }
\keys_define:nn { fontspec }
 {
  Color .code:n = \msg_warning:nnn { RobtA } { invalid-key } { #1 },
  Colour .code:n = \msg_warning:nnn { RobtA } { invalid-key } { #1 },
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Abc {\addfontfeatures{Color=red} Abc}

\end{document}
```

Comment: My code only improves iteratively. You may have noticed some recently improvements.... Structuring the code to follow these guidelines was coming up soon on my list :) Normalising indentation also!!

Comment: @WillRobertson Uh-oh. Sounds like I might need to read the guidelines, if they are going to be implemented ;)

Comment: @RobtA It's still not clear what you're doing to `\addfontfeatures`; I can't think to any reason for modifying it.

Comment: That detailed reply gives me a lot to think about, egreg. Some of my code is careless: If it works, I leave it that way, and do not ask why. This might be the time for me to review all of it. My rationale for intercepting the normal `\addfontfeatures` code: In my application Color and Opacity are banned. Setting xcolor to monochrome or grayscale does not block the fontspec features. So, I coded a way to intercept any disallowed feature setting, at the level of my own document class. Thus `{\addfontfeature{Color=something} text}` produces a class error, when it see the Color.

Comment: @RobtA Please open an issue in the fontspec repository for me to add a mechanism to disable keys... I can see the potential use that you've described

Comment: @WillRobertson Issue opened. My GitHub ID is RobtAll, not RobtA (who is a different person there).

Comment: @RobtA I added a better way for disabling a key. Of course a general method provided by `fontspec` would be useful as well.

Comment: Tested key disabling (I added Opacity). Works. Mentioned over at fontspec github.

Answer (score 0):

Since egreg asked, I will show why I am using the code. Here is another MWE that exactly illustrates my strategy:

```
% !TeX program = LuaLaTeX
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[gray]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xstring}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\def\mycheckfeature#1{}
%% Uncomment to see the difference:
% \def\mycheckfeature#1{%
%   \IfSubStr{#1}{Color}{%
%     \ClassError{mine}{You cannot add Color as font feature}%
%     {Remove the Color font feature from your text.}%
%   }{}%
%   \IfSubStr{#1}{Colour}{%
%     \ClassError{mine}{You cannot add Color as font feature}%
%     {Remove the Color font feature from your text.}%
%   }{}%
% }
%%
\ExplSyntaxOn
\let\myaddfontfeatures\addfontfeatures
\let\addfontfeatures\relax
\let\addfontfeature\relax
\DeclareDocumentCommand \AddFontFeatures { m } {%
  \mycheckfeature{#1}%
  \myaddfontfeatures{#1}%
}
\let\addfontfeatures\AddFontFeatures
\let\addfontfeature\AddFontFeatures
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
It was a dark and story night. Lord Withens mounted his \textcolor{brown}{brown horse} and rode through the gloom to the {\addfontfeatures{Color=009900}Green Castle}.\par
\end{document}
```

Required `[gray]{xcolor}` prevents the brown horse from appearing in brown text; it appears in grayscale. But it does not prevent the Green Castle from being green, since fontspec uses a different strategy that is not controlled by xcolor.

Uncomment the code, and see how an error message appears at the Green Castle.

I also use that with Opacity. And, I also intercept `\setmainfont` and similar commands. It works. There are also places where I intercept a forbidden user setting, and provide my own message with instructions.